# C# Cannot convert randomized string into the Textbox

Tags: c#

```
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string[] words = new string[10];
        words[0] = "Starks";
        words[1] = "Lannisters";
        words[2] = "Tullys";
        words[3] = "Greyjoys";
        words[4] = "Arryns";
        words[5] = "Baratheons";
        words[6] = "Tyrells";
        words[7] = "Martells";
        words[8] = "Targaryans";
        words[9] = "Braavosi";

        Random rword = new Random();


        int randomNumber = rword.Next(10);

        string asterickWordIntial = words[randomNumber].ToUpper();
        string nonAsterickWord = words[randomNumber].ToUpper();

        string asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("A", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("B", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("C", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("D", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("E", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("F", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("G", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("H", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("I", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("J", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("K", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("L", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("M", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("N", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("O", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("P", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("Q", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("R", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("S", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("T", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("U", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("V", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("W", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("X", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("Y", "*");
        asterickWordFinal = asterickWordIntial.Replace("Z", "*");

        asterickWordFinal = HangTxtBox;
    }
```

When I set asterickWordFinal to HangTxtBox I'm getting a the following message

"Cannot implicitly convert type System.Window.Forms.TextBox to string"

But I heard if you set asterickWordFinal.Text = HangTxtBox would get to it right, however I'm getting this message.

"string does not contain a definition for Text accepting a first argument for of type string could be found"

So I'm I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the system, the namespace or do I have to try to override? Thank you for the help!

Comment: It goes the other way, the assignee goes on the left. `HangTxtBox.Text = asterickWordFinal;`

Comment: use it like this HangTxtBox.Text= asterickWordFinal

Comment: why not do something like `asterickWordFinal = Regex.Replace(astrickWordIntial, "[a-zA-Z]", "*")`? that would save having to write so many replace statements.

Comment: You need to learn from the exception messages. I know they sound confusing at the start, but it was telling you the program couldn't put a Textbox into a string! Since what you wanted to do was put a string into a textbox this is a good hint that you had the assignment backwards! (As textboxes aren't just string elements you can't directly assign a string into one though. They have a Text property which is a string though, so you can assign the string you have generated to that.)

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backwards.  The `=` assignment operator doesn't take the *left* value and put it in the *right* variable, it takes the *right* value and puts it in the *left* variable.  Like this:

```
HangTxtBox.Text = asterickWordFinal;
```

This essentially means:

> Take the value of `asterickWordFinal` and put it in `HangTxtBox.Text`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the value of the textbox? if so it should be like this `asterickWordFinal = Convert.ToString(HangTxtBox.Text);`

Comment: The last line of the code you posted means that you are like assigning the value of the textbox into the variable if im not mistaken

Answer (score -1):

This is a side-answer, your asterisk code can be simplified quite a bit. All you are really doing is creating a string that has as many asterisks as there are letters in the random word you pick.

You can actually do that quite easily like so:

```
...

string asterickWordIntial = words[randomNumber].ToUpper();

// create a string with the * character repeated as many times as the
// length of the random word
string asterickWordFinal = new string('*', asterickWordInitial.Length);

HangTxtBox.Text = asterickWordFinal;
```

Note that your code assumes no words can have non-letter characters, which is probably fine for hangman, you just have to make sure you know that when generating the word list.

Comment: This is more suited for a comment, not an answer. it does not answer his question.

Comment: @Dispersia Do you not see the character length of this?

Comment: "All you are really doing is creating a string that has as many asterisks as there are letters in the random word you pick.

You can actually do that quite easily like so:`string asterickWordFinal = new string('*', asterickWordInitial.Length)`" Regardless of length, it's not an answer. It's a comment.

Comment: @Disperia I'm not disputing whether or not it's more suited as a comment. I actually like to explain things, especially to beginners, which it's obvious that the OP is. I also like formatting. What exactly was your intended purpose on commenting on something that is two days old? You're just wasting both of our time.